# Persist text file on iPhone or Simulator and read it from Mac

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

I would like to filter an existing word list (text file or web resource) using [UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:word] like this:

```
NSMutableArray * validWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[words count]];
for (NSString * word in words)
{
    if ([UIReferenceLibraryViewController dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm:word])
    {
        [validWords addObject:word];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"reject word: %@", word);
    }
}
```

Using either my iPhone or the Xcode 4 device simulator, how can I persist the resulting NSMutableArray validWords to a location that I can access from my Mac?

**Edit:** This is meant to be a one-time operation, so anything that allows me to get the data off the device or simulator is fine. I've considered implementing a web service on my host machine to read/write the (large) text file, but was wondering if there is a more direct way to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you looking for solution that you can implement in a commercial application?  Or do you just need to be able to browse to the file you've created using the iOS simulator? Also, do you need the file to be human-readable as text, or do you plan to deserialize it on the Mac side?

Comment: Good questions: this is just a one-time operation (so while interesting, iCloud might be overkill if there is a more direct way to access the file system of the simulator). I can deserialize it if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of the iOS simulator, you can conveniently write to a file on your Desktop. The app's directory is located somewhere:

```
/Users/me/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/ABC/Library/Caches
```

So to write your valid words array to a plist on the Desktop, use:

```
NSString *caches = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *path = [caches stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/../../../../../../../../Desktop/words.plist"];
[validWords writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
```

Less fun, but much easier would be to just write it to a file in the Caches dir en open that in Finder. This also works on the device: Go to `Xcode organizer > Devices > Applications` and choose `Download`.

Comment: This works as advertised, just what I was looking for! I assume this will work in reverse (meaning I can read a file from the same location as well)?

Comment: Yes, with the iOS simulator you can also read from that file. Think of the iOS simulator as a Mac OS X app, with full access to the file system. NB: do not submit this code to the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [`iCloud`](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/documents.html) to get data from your iDevice to your Mac (and back).

Comment: Very good idea, although since it is only a one-time operation (sorry forgot to mention that in my original post which I just edited), it might be a bit overkill. Still +1 in case someone is looking for the same functionality but needs it repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.  I haven't tested - but you get the idea.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *applicationSupportDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *wordsPath = [paths stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"words.txt"];

FILE *filePointer = fopen([wordsPath UTF8String],"w");
[words enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    fprintf(filePointer,"%s\n",[obj UTF8String]);
}];
fclose(filePointer);
```

Then you should be able to browse to the app in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` etc.  `words.txt` should be there.